# The lexical analysis part: analyse ?: as an operator instead of separator

Tags: compilation, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

My target is to implement a very simple lexical analysis of the **C** language, such as when you read an expression **ab=3**, then It will be analysed as:

```
ID<ab> OP<=> LIT<8>   (op will be "operator",LIT will be "literal").
```

There is also an situation when you read an expression **a ? b :c**. normally it will be analysed as

```
ID<a> SEP<?> ID<b> SEP<:> ID<c>".
```

but as we know It actually is the ternary operator. So the analysis listed above is not correct.

Now I just want to refer to a compiler such as gcc, g++ and check how do these compilers implement the lexical analysis? Anyone who can give me an suggestion ?

Comment: So if you want it as an operator why  are you scanning it as a separator? What's the question here?

Comment: Because I got this resource from others. Both "?" and ":" are processed as separator by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes that lexer output incorrect? You are thinking too far ahead and trying to solve parse problems in the lexer.  If you really like, you could change ? to be an operator (as it should be in this case), but ultimately it doesn't matter, just parse using the terminals you have defined as tokens.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Because I am new to this project, still can't distinguish the usage of lexical and syntax analyzer. By this time, It's still a little earlier to resolve this kind of issue. I will check this again later.